# ASP.NEt WebForms UserControl: Why is overriding .Visible causing a System.StackOverflowException?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, overriding, stack-overflow

I have a custom UserControl whose .Visible property I need to set to True or False.  However, if the UserControl's first child control is a Panel and its ID is cMain, I want it to set the Panel's .Visible property instead of the UserControl's.  Here's my code:

Here's the custom class I use:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyControl : Inherits UserControl

    Public Overrides Property Visible As Boolean
        Get
            Return GetVisible()
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            SetVisible(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Function GetVisible() As Boolean

        Dim c As Control = GetMain()

        If TypeOf c Is Panel Then
            Return c.Visible
        Else
            Return MyBase.Visible
        End If

    End Function

    Sub SetVisible(Value As Boolean)

        Dim c As Control = GetMain()

        If TypeOf c Is Panel Then
            c.Visible = Value
        Else
            MyBase.Visible = Value
        End If

    End Sub

    Function GetMain() As Control

        Dim c As Control = If(Controls.Count = 0, Nothing, Controls(0))

        If Not (TypeOf c Is Panel AndAlso c.ID = "cMain") Then c = Me

        Return c

    End Function

End Class
```

Here's the actual UserControl itself:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TestControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="JsonJqueryDevex.TestControl1" %>
<asp:Panel ID="cMain" runat="server">
inside
</asp:Panel>
outside
```

UserControl's codebehind:

```
Public Class TestControl1
    Inherits MyControl

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's the markup to implement it into the host page:

```
<uc:TestControl ID="ucTest" Visible="true" runat="server"></uc:TestControl>
```

Notice that I overrode .Visible within my base clase.  I did this so that I could call MyBase if the control being referenced is the UserControl itself.  Otherwise, I assume it's the Panel control.  When I load the page, I get `System.StackOverflowException`.  What's funny is that I don't get this when I have the custom control's Visible property set to `false` in the markup.

The stack trace shows that it's getting caught in .Visible's get accessor when it calls `Return GetVisible()`.  If it's a Panel, it will execute `Return c.Visible`.  However, as soon as I reference .Visible when c is a Panel, it breaks back into MyControl's .Visible get accessor.  I don't know how this is possible since I am only overriding my custom control's Visible property, but it's acting as if I am overriding the Panel's .Visible property.  What is going on here?

Comment: Have you set breakpoints? What is the value of `Controls(0)` within your `GetMain()` method? Often times static text in the markup (even whitespace) can end up as a `LiteralControl` in the `Controls` collection. If this is your case, then your condition will always return `Me`, thus the infinite loop and cause of `StackOverflowException`

Comment: No, it is the Panel for sure.  As you can see in the code, I force it to check the type and also the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the behavior of [`Control.Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx).

Your program is working when the value is `false` because it simply returns `false` at the point that it is checked. However, a control will not return `true` for `.Visible` **unless** both the control is visible **and the parent is visible**.

What's happening in your case is that, when `true`, the parent is checking a child control for its `.Visible` value, and any child controls will check its parent (your user control) in addition to its own `.Visible` value. This is where your infinite recursion loop occurs, causing the stack overflow.

Comment: Interesting! I use 'new' keyword instead of 'override' keyword and it works normaly.